# Suppose $X$ has density function $f(x)$ for $-1\leq x\leq1$ and 0 otherwise. Find the density function of $Y=\vert X\vert$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The answer is $f(-y)+f(y)$ for $-1\leq y\leq1$ but I don't see how that answer was reached using the formula $g(s(y))s'(y)$.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the pdf of $Y$ may be more intuitively reached by first finding an expression for the cdf of $Y$.

Comment: I just tried this $$P(Y\leq y)=P(\vert X\vert\leq y)$$
$$=P(X\leq\pm y)$$
$$=\begin{cases} P(X\leq y) & x>0\\
P(X\leq-y) & x<0\end{cases}$$
$$=f(y)+f(-y)$$

Comment: More accurately, the probability is $F_X(y)-F_X(-y)$. For the density, differentiate, we get $f(y)+f(-y)$ (for positive $y$).

Comment: How do you know you have to subtract $F_X(y)$ and $F_X(-y)$?

Comment: The probability that $-y\le X\le y$ is $\Pr(X\le y)-\Pr(X\lt -y)$. Just draw a number line, put down dots at $-y$ and $y$.